# I need to make a scatterplot from a csv file containg date on the x axis and time on the y axis, how do i code this?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I need to create a scatterplot that contains the Date on the X axis and the Time on the Y axis. The date looks like (4/10/2019) and the time looks like (23:55:00) if this matters.

I have tried the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv("Crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv")
plt.scatter(df["Date_1"],df["Time_1"])
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Time', fontsize=16)
plt.title('Occurence of Crime in Relation to Time',fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

My error message:

> ```
> ====================== RESTART: F:\scatter plot code.py ======================
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "F:\scatter plot code.py", line 6, in <module>
>     df = pd.read_csv("Crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv")
>   File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
>     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>   File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 429, in _read
>     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
>   File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
>     self._make_engine(self.engine)
>   File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
>     self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
>   File "C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
>     self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
>   File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
>   File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 705, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv' does not exist: b'Crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv'
> ```

I am totally lost, I appreciate any help!

I expected a scatterplot.

Comment: The final line of the stack trace indicates that it is a FileNotFoundError. Are you running this in the same directory as your csv file? If so, double check the spelling of your filename. If not, either move the csv to the same directory, or provide the full path i.e. pd.read_csv("C://PATH_TO_FILE/yourfile.csv")

Answer (score 0):

You can also try including the full path of your csv file.

```
df = pd.read_csv("THE FULL PATH TO YOUR FILE")
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check your .csv file name is correct;
Then try put your .csv file "Crimes_-_2001_to_present.csv"  and your .py code in the same folder;
Run;
if not ok: change your .csv file name to simple way, such as "Crimes2001.csv";
.py file change by: `df = pd.read_csv(r"Crimes2001.csv")`;
Run again, then  it must be ok!